# What quirks are in the Blackberry Web Browser that a developer should be aware of?

Tags: browser, blackberry

Before I start pulling my hair out on any "known issues", is there any quirks or problems that I should be aware of.

Specifically with cookies, JavaScript, HTML, CSS and images.

PS I have a copy of the docs provided by RIM, but I'm hoping others know of some lesser known issues.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few that I've noticed:

- For some reason, the BB browser doesn't seem to handle underscores in the hostname correctly.  I don't remember what happened, but if you hostname is like this:  http://some_host/blah, I remember it having problems.

  - This can be corrected with a DNS entry that removes the _
- Another thing we've seen is serving up .jad files for Java downloads.  If your module contains _ or other special characters, the BB browser displays a HTTP 500 error when trying to fetch the .jar or parse the .jad.  This is especially annoying because it's not actually an HTTP error, the server is serving up a file, but the BB browser just can't parse it, so it blames the server.

  - We fixed this by using Fiddler to hit the .jad URL and view the contents of the HTTP response.  If your .jad has any special characters (or sometimes URL/HTTP encoded strings) you might need to simplify your module name to only use A-Za-z0-9

I know those aren't exactly html/css things, but thought I'd post this anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I had used the **blackberry browsers on emulator versions to test my web pages**. 
These are some i would like to point out.

Please forgive me in case of any deviation with a real case because **these are specific to emulator versions on windows 7 OS**. I dint have the devices to check and verify.

1. When we are coming down to a BB OS version below 5.X (eg. BB 9630), the browsers support for java script will be turned off by default. So you need to go browser options turn on it manually.
2. When we go further down to BB OS version 4.2, the style sheet support will be turned off by default. Causing your webpages to render without applying style sheet. So that time you need both the java script and style sheet supports to be turned on manually.
3. Even when i was on a OS version 7.X or 6.X, the internet connection was working and i could connect to pages. When i went down to version 5, those emulator browsers shown issues for connection. On googling i found that MDS is a requirement when we go down the versions and seek internet access.
4. I installed MDS, still it was not working for versions below 6, reason being the JAVA_HOME environment variable was not set in my advanced system settings in my-computer properties. But it was not even pointing out the issue and the MDS was closing instantly. 
   So after setting my JAVA_HOME to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_07" the place i installed JDK(we need JDK for MDS), internet connection started working.
5. Also if you are using g zip compression for your pages, below Blackberry OS version 6, the browsers no longer requests for a compressed one. (found it on OS version 5 emulators BB 9700,BB 8520).
6. Also when you are going to use a css property or html entity that you doubt support, be sure to go to the corresponding OS version content developer guide and find from which version are they providing the full support and partial support.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [BlackBerry Browser Version 4.2 Content Developer Guide](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/1143/browser_devguide.pdf).  It is for the older 4.2 browser but still has lots of good info about what HTML, CSS, and javascript is supported.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with BB 8700 is that you should not use JavaScript, neither depend on CSS to be rendered correctly. It also has no flash player by default so you're off to plain server-side HTML form processing/ASP/CGI. Also beware of size, as internet can get pretty slow while on the road.

Answer (score 0):

One known issue is that the Blackberry browser completely ignores the css display property, so you can't use display:none to hide content.

We've also had trouble with basic form submittal - sometimes, the POST doesn't happen at all, other times it happens but some or all of the form fields go AWOL. We haven't been able to get to the bottom of this issue, but it seems to occur mostly with the BB Curve series.